# Update Cordova version from 2.9 to 9.0

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to update the oldest phonegap's project (with cordova 2.9 in core) to fresh cordova 9.0 version. I created a new project and replaced there all code.

Now i have a great problem:

```
[27.03 11:48:42] [main] [INFO ] ActivityIndex - deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. @ 1205: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js
[27.03 11:48:42] [main] [INFO ] ActivityIndex - Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady @ 1198: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js
[27.03 11:48:42] [main] [INFO ] ActivityIndex - Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady @ 1198: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js
```

But, if i removed the `cordova_plugins.js` - event is work! What a hell?

**Index.js**

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },

    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
    // 'pause', 'resume', etc.
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        console.log('[DEBUG] device is ready');
        serviceModel.startService();
    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {

    }
};

app.initialize();
```

**cordova_plugins.js**

```
cordova.define('cordova/plugin_list', function(require, exports, module) {
module.exports = [];
module.exports.metadata = 
// TOP OF METADATA
{
  "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3"
};
// BOTTOM OF METADATA
});
```

So, why it happens? How i can solve it? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

reinstall all plugins & platforms from the project folder.
Add new platforms(android & iOS).
The cordova_plugin.js file will be automatically included.
Create new build & test again.
Hope this works.

Comment: Try manually including cordova_plugins.js file in index.html, unless you are using any native plugins you don't need this file. You can skip it if not needed. Your app will work regardless of it